# How to brew cask install older android-sdk

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager, homebrew-cask

I am trying to install android-sdk 25.2.3 but I can't find any document on installing the older version of android-sdk
brew cask install android-sdk

Answer (score 1):

this is what I found to make it all work on Sierra ...

- brew tap caskroom/cask
- brew cask install android-sdk
- add **ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk** to your profile
- add **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk** to your profile
- sdkmanager --list; #shows all available platforms
- sdkmanager "platforms;android-25" "build-tools;25.0.2" (install platform)
- sdkmanager --licenses; #license agreement

hope this could help